# Webpack loading remote module on an incorrect endpoint

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am using webpack's module federation plugin for a microfrontend architecture.

The container app sends a request to the following

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'container',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        huddle: 'microfrontend@{domain}/AdditionalDir/remoteEntry.js'
      },

    })
```

For more context both frontends are on nginx pods served through a kubernetes cluster and the requests also get handled through an nginx proxy.

RemoteEntry.js gets loaded fine however the chunks get loaded like this domain/hash.js while i want it to load like this {domain}/AdditionalDir/hash.js is there a way to specify where i load my remote modules from ?? I've tried playing around with the publicPath in webpack's config with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried editing the public path at runtime?
https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#on-the-fly

Comment: @AnthonyMattice I've tried explicitly setting the endpoint in the example above to /AdditionalDir/ with no luck does changing it on the fly matter ?

Comment: The difference is one is static and the other is dynamically generated. I can't say for sure that it would make a difference, but it does offer flexibility between environments, and wouldn't hurt to try. `const currentScriptSrc = document.currentScript.src;` `__webpack_public_path__ = new URL(currentScriptSrc).origin + '/AdditionalDir/';
`